# Not able to set specific value in dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My dropdown box is of type "Input" and its values are listed using table.I'm able to set different values in dropdown box using the following code

```
element = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropDownId"));
_driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", element, "value");
```

But the dropdown is not accepting the value which is listed as first option.
For example dropdown options are

1. Windows
2. Linux

I couldn't set Windows as the value. But if i set another value first and then change to windows,it is working fine. What could be the reason for this ?

```
<input class="dxeEditArea_VMware dxeEditAreaSys " name="ctl00$ctl00$MasterContent$MainContentPlaceHolder$MachineRequestTabs$RuntimePropertiesContainer$CloneSpec$gc_CloneSpec" id="ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec_I" onchange="aspxETextChanged('ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec')" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec')" type="text" onkeydown="aspxEKeyDown('ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec', event)" style="cursor:default;" autocomplete="off" readonly="">

<table id="ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec_DDD_L_LBT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                                            <tbody><tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow_VMware">
                                                <td class="dxeListBoxItem_VMware dxeListBoxItemHover_VMware" id="ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec_DDD_L_LBI0T0">Windows</td>
                                            </tr><tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow_VMware">
                                                <td class="dxeListBoxItem_VMware" id="ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_MainContentPlaceHolder_MachineRequestTabs_RuntimePropertiesContainer_CloneSpec_gc_CloneSpec_DDD_L_LBI1T0">Linux</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
```

This is the html for combox box and table which has the values

Comment: Share your HTML first...:)

Comment: I have added the html above

Comment: Is there Id attribute value of the element is unique or dynamically generated??

Comment: I think the issue is the dropdown is not accepting the value. Even if i click enter after setting the value, it is not accepting. How to make the dropdown accept the new value ?